# Forge Server crashes on start up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

When I start up my server that I am hosting locally, it will load normally until the very end when it will give me the error

```
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_213211_a(MinecraftServer.java:538) ~[?:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:betterweather.mixins.json:server.MixinMinecraftServer,pl:mixin:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71260_j(MinecraftServer.java:568) ~[?:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:betterweather.mixins.json:server.MixinMinecraftServer,pl:mixin:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71260_j(DedicatedServer.java:514) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240802_v_(MinecraftServer.java:679) ~[?:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:betterweather.mixins.json:server.MixinMinecraftServer,pl:mixin:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240783_a_(MinecraftServer.java:232) ~[?:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:betterweather.mixins.json:server.MixinMinecraftServer,pl:mixin:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?] {}
```